# Electron failing to navigate

Tags: navigation, electron, onbeforeunload

If both loadURL and location.href are silently failing to navigate on certain sites when using Electron JS, you may be running into the same issue that's been kicking me in the shins for the last 4 hours

Answer (score 0):

Many sites will add an onbeforeunload event listener to prevent users navigating away from the page with unsaved changes. Unfortunately, Electron doesn't render confirmation dialogs so instead of being presented with a "are you sure" style popup you get nothing if you try to navigate on sites that have this listener.

To prevent this problem you'll either need to stop using onbeforeunload or add a custom dialog as per https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7977 if you control the site. Or if you don't control the site you're loading, use something like the following to prevent the site listening for unload

```
// Override addEventListener so we can block any attempt to beforeunload. 
let originalAddEventListener = window.addEventListener.bind(window)
Object.defineProperty(window, 'addEventListener', {
    configurable: false,
    writeable: false,
    get () {
        return function addEventListener (event, ...args) {
            if (event === 'beforeunload') {
                console.log("NO")
            }
            else {
                originalAddEventListener(event, ...args)
            }
        }
    }
})

Object.defineProperty(window, 'onbeforeunload', {
    configurable: false,
    set () {
    },
    get () {
    }
})
```